# Как работают групповые роуты в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Интересует методика обработки групповых роутов в Laravel:

```
Route::prefix('sort')->group(function () {
   Route::get('down', 'Controller@increaseSort');
   Route::get('up', 'Controller@decreaseSort');
});
```

Каким образом, с помощью какого механизма, вложенные роуты понимают, что они именно в этой группе, и что они вообще вложенные?

Я бы понял, если бы было, например, так:

```
Route:group(function ($route) {
   $route->get('down', 'Controller@increaseSort');
   $route->get('up', 'Controller@decreaseSort');
});
```

Но первый алгоритм мне вообще не понятен.

Comment: В данном контексте не вижу групповых роутов, честно говоря.

Comment: @InDevX Route::group

Comment: Вот, вы добавили префикс - теперь вижу.. А тут логика простая - group и указывает на группу... Префикс = первая часть ссылки, дальше э-ты группы идут (`sort/down`, `sort/up`)

Comment: @InDevX вопрос не в том как они работают на выходе, и какие у них префиксы/мидлвары. 
Вопрос в том, как они вообще формируются внутри. Ведь, вызывая в группах фасады роутов, мы ничего не возвращаем из замыкания. Да у самого замыкания нет аргументов, которые можно было бы изменить.

Comment: Откройте метод `group()` и посмотрите что там творится. Если Не понятно - тогда задавайте вопросы.

Comment: @InDevX метод group вызывает метод group другого класса, потом еще куча всего и куча всего магического. Скажу больше - вы даже метод get  найдете у Роутера. Не все так просто.

Comment: Такие вопросы, хоть смейся, хоть плачь.. Я вот даже хз как это объяснить. Создаётся некий объект, ему добавляются свойства. Как эл-ты понимают что они часть объекта?

Comment: @InDevX Хороший вопрос, мне вот тоже интересно, как объекты в замыкании понимают, что они находятся в другом объекте? Как они получают своего родителя-врапера?

Comment: Это был риторический вопрос. Объектам в замыкании не надо знать своего родителя. Сперва префикс срабатывает, потом ищутся все его групповые эл-ты

Comment: @InDevX ok. Как префикс передается групповым элементам, если из замыкания ничего не возвращается и ничего в него не передается?

Comment: Вы издеваетесь с меня, что ли? )) Откройте файл [файл](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/Router.php) посмотрите в нём функцию `group()` (366 строка) а потом ф-ю `updateGroupStack()`(384 строка) и там всё понятно (даже если тупо названия перевести) и не возникает никаких вопросов.